# How do I declare a const in a header?

Tags: c++, header, constants

I want to test defining a const in a header and use it in functions, then call it. However I get the error, I added include guards which doesn't help. Error is: LNK1169: One or more defined multiply symbols found. How can i do it in a nother way? Is declaring const in .h and defining this const in .cpp and then including this .cpp in all other .cpps the only solution?

**Header**

```
#ifndef STORY
#define STORY
const int x = 4;
#endif
```

**.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "8-04.h"

void func1()
{
    int w = x;
    std::cout << "func1 " << w << std::endl;
}
```

**.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "8-04.h"

void func2()
{
    int z = x;
    std::cout << "func2 " << z << std::endl;
}
```

**main**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "8-04.h"
#include "8-04first.cpp"
#include "8-04second.cpp"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    func1();
    func2();
}
```

Comment: Related: `#include "anyfile.cpp"` is a bad idea no matter what. You `#include` *headers*; you compile and link .cpp's.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong that would cause a multiple definition here.

Comment: Unless he's compiling all of the cpps...

Comment: @Salgar that must be it. The problem wouldn't be with the const though (as the title suggests), but with the functions.

Comment: Side note: you can bury `x` in a legacy `enum { x = 4 }` if you want (very-well may once you fix your double-stack of .cpp woes).

Comment: It's VS compiler. if I don't include .cpps in main I get 
error C3861: 'func1': identifier not found, the same for 'func2'

Comment: @beginh thats because you need to provide a function prototype in a header file, and #include that header

Comment: @mjs Ah ok now i get the idea properly, about linking. thank you for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that each .cpp includes the .h. This means that each .o contains a `const int x`. When the linker links these together, you get multiple definitions.

The solution is to modify the .h

```
#ifndef STORY
#define STORY
extern const int x;  //Do not initialise
#endif
```

and in *a single* .cpp:

`const int x=4`

**Edit:**
I didnt even see the `#include <file.cpp>` business. Don't do that. Its horrible.

Comment: `#include "file.cpp` isnt different from `#include "file.h"`. Its just about how these files were intended to be used. Youre of course right that its not good practice, however there ARE some case where including files other than headers is useful.

Answer (score 0):

This should be like :

header.h:

```
#ifndef STORY
#define STORY
const int x = 4;
void func1();
void func2();
#endif
```

fun1.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "header.h"

void func1()
{
    int w = x;
    std::cout << "func1 " << w << std::endl;
}
```

fun2.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "header.h"

void func2()
{
    int z = x;
    std::cout << "func2 " << z << std::endl;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "header.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    func1();
    func2();
}
```

You can not include ".cpp"

Answer (score 0):

It can be done such as :

header.h:

```
#ifndef STORY
#define STORY
const int x = 4;
void func1();
void func2();
#endif
```

fun1.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "header.h"
using namespace std;

void func1()
{
    int w = x;
    cout << "func1 value of w = " << w << "\n";
}
```

fun2.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "header.h"
using namespace std;

void func2()
{
    int z = x;
    cout << "func2 value of z = " << z << "\n";
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "header.h"

int main()
{
    func1();
    func2();
}
```

".cpp" file cannot be included in main source file.